# How to 'combine' histories of two files (one being the older 'version' of the other one)

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I basically have what's a poor-man's versioning...

- At one point someone **copied / renamed the 'file.cs' to 'old-file.cs'** - and all its history up to that point going with it.
- And then created **a new 'file.cs'** - with all the new history going forward.

I ended up with **the same file having history split up in between** these two files.

I know this must be simple (if possible),
- I've tried searching, but **my problem is how to 'phrase the question'**
- This isn't a 'merge' (I think - I don't have branches involved),
- It's not the typical 'move' either
- I've looked up the [tf command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0.aspx) but nothing resembles what I need
- I have the [TFS Source Control Explorer Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8ad891d2-142b-4acf-b487-46db9f3bb5cf) installed (but it can't really help with this)

FWIW, I'm using the VS 2015, C# project (both files are part of the same project), though I don't mind if the solution is command line 'tf' or whatever gets the job done.

So if anyone could help point me to the right direction at least it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested with TFS 2015.3 + VS 2015.3, but couldn't reproduce your scenario. In my test, the history in old file has been migrated to new file. You may check my steps to see whether they are the same as yours:

1. Rename a file gulpfile.js to old-gulpfile.js, and check it in in Source Control Explorer. Then copy old-gulpfile.js in workspace and modify it to gulpfile.js, and add it to source control and check it in.

[image]

2. Check old-gulpfile.js history:

[image]

3. Check gulpfile.js history:

[image]

You can see all history in old-gulpfile.js is also in new gulpfile.js file.

Comment: Cece thanks for your reply - TFS is the '14.102.25619.0' (I believe that's latest). I'm sure your right (and very helpful info for similar situations), but it's not as if I'm doing it right now. It's 'de facto' current state of two files' history, that were copied and renamed - but that was a while ago (and team member that did that may have had different setup). So, I have a problem at hand I'd like to solve - when I look into history, first file history ends, where the copy file history starts - and nothing to click/expand like with rename.

Comment: I assume your team member created a new file instead of copying it. You may perform a merge between old file and new file, for example, merge from old file to new file, and then take target version when there is conflict.   (Make sure merge won't break your file) In this way, you can see the history in old file will show in new file.

Comment: thanks Cece - that actually helped (didn't have time to test/try). It's not well documented (how the merge really works w/ histories) but I've tried a few things and got what I needed in the end. Since files have no 'merge relationship' the baseless merge is needed (manually enter TFS urls). Then the other thing is selecting the right target changeset to do the merge into (it offers latest but I need the first one actually). And to see changes check in is needed. I'll edit the question, and your answer (if you have nothing against it:) to add all the info in. Thanks again.